# angular ui.bootstrap not working

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am having some trouble getting the popover element to work in an angular app using ui.bootstrap - here is some code:

in the app.js file, I am requiring ui.bootstrap

```
angular.module('developerPortalApp', [
    'ui.bootstrap'
  ])
```

The html element I am trying to attach a popover to

```
<div ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
    <a href="#" popover-placement="right" popover="On the Right!">how do I register?</a>
</div>
```

The popover content isn't going to be dynamic so there isn't anything in the controller for that. This is my first time using angular-bootstrap, so, is there something simple that I'm missing?

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: I should also add that ui-bootstrap-tpls.js is being loaded with the page

Answer (score 4):

May be you are missing some script file:-

Here is working example of your question:-

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
      <a href="#" popover-placement="right" popover="On the Right!">how do I register?</a>

</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/E2LbaCoHKHKzifeL5Hny?p=preview

Comment: Well, admittedly I'm at somewhat of a loss. I seem to have things setup correctly according to this but it still isn't working. The only other difference I can think of is that the <a> tag I'm trying to place the popover on is contained within a jumbotron and a form, but I don't see how that would affect things :(

Comment: Can you make a plunker ?

Comment: I checked it with jumbotron and form it is still working :-)

http://plnkr.co/edit/E2LbaCoHKHKzifeL5Hny?p=preview

Comment: I did not test what I am about to say, but to confirm the popover working in plunker, you should be using uib version of popover.  Bootstrap CSS uses just popover.

Comment: @user1889992, I, for one, had to remove uib- prefix to get it working on a yeoman scaffolded app. uib- prefix was introduced in 0.14.0 as documented here https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/wiki/Migration-guide-for-prefixes

Comment: I was using version 0.10.0... removing the uib- fixed it for me.